# Samba4: Public Share

Tags: samba

since the update of MacOS Yosemite I would like to use a newer Samba version (V4) because it supports SMB2 and SMB3. I'm using it for my developer VM's and after the update to Samba4 my old public share does not work anymore. I found out that the security = user needs to be set and that map to guest = Bad User needs to be. But it does not work. Every time when I try to connect it asks for a password.

Details:

```
OS: Centos6.5
Samba: 4.0.0rc4
```

Here is the current config:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
guest account = vagrant
follow symlinks = Yes
wide links = Yes
unix password sync = Yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

[development]
comment = Development
path = /var/development
public = Yes
read only = No
writeable = Yes
browseable = Yes
guest ok = Yes
```

And the following part is the connection string:

```
mount_smbfs cifs://192.168.177.12/development/ ./development
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `map to guest = Bad Password` from here http://serverfault.com/questions/470650/samba-configuration-for-public-shares

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the parameters for follow symlinks and wide links moved to the share section.

Here are the config which works:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = bad user
guest account = vagrant
dns proxy = no
unix extensions = no

[development]
comment = Development
path = /var/development
read only = no
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```

Comment: Thank you - for me it was lacking the "guest ok = Yes" line in the share definition.